# REGEX start with two metacharacters

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have one problem with my REGEX. i would like to search the segments of my string who start with ," and must contains one line break or more.

```
$csv = xxxx,xxxx,"segment with

line break",xxxx,"segment with no line break",xxxx;
```

This is my REGEX :

```
$file = fopen('google.csv', 'r');

$csv = file_get_contents('google.csv');


function matches($matches)
{
    return preg_replace("#\n|\r|\t#", "£", $matches);

}

preg_replace_callback('/,"(?=[^"]*\R)[^"]*"/', 'matches', $csv);
```

When I delete the first metacharacter ',' it's works but I have some problems with the rest of the string. And when I add the comma, my REGEX don't works.

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: How does it not work? - https://regex101.com/r/2q5ijI/2

Comment: He work with all the generator regex web sites with my CSV file, but not with my local server ...

Comment: Did you try it like this? https://3v4l.org/ZP8bh

Comment: Yes I try it exactly like this, and when I have two metacharacters to start the REGEX, the function doesn't work. That so strange !

Comment: I try with backslash too and it's the same result

Comment: Can you add to your question how you are processing the csv file?

Comment: Of course, it's done

Comment: Thanks, it's done ! But I have the same result, the comma is problematic

Comment: So this result is not ok? https://3v4l.org/9DZW9

Comment: I try directly with my csv on 3v4l.org, it's works. On my local server it's doesn't works.. I don't understand

Comment: When you run it on your local server, what is the outcome of `$csv = file_get_contents('google.csv');
var_dump($csv);`

Comment: it's : string(5818)"blablablablabla..." blablabla is the file

Comment: @ErwanVillemont Can you add this temporarily to the top of your page to see if there is an error? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument of preg_replace must be a string:

```
preg_replace("#\n|\r|\t#", "£", $matches[0]);
//                                      ^^^
```

The whole code:

```
$csv = 'xxxx,xxxx,"segment with

line break",xxxx,"segment with no line break",xxxx';

function matches($matches) {
    return preg_replace("#\n|\r|\t#", "£", $matches[0]);
}

$res = preg_replace_callback('/,"(?=[^"]*\R)[^"]*"/', 'matches', $csv);
echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
xxxx,xxxx,"segment with££line break",xxxx,"segment with no line break",xxxx
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help ! I change it, but I have the same result, the comma is problematic

Comment: @ErwanVillemont: Works for me. What do you mean by "don't work"? What is the result?

Comment: I have no result, when I print_r the new result, it's the same that the original file, he can't find the REGEX with the comma in first place. He works on generator web sites, not in my local server. But without the comma, my local server find all results start with ". I don't understand

Comment: That exactly what I have. I have update MAMP and the result it's the same